# Проблемы с выводом массива. Java

Tags: java, массивы, консоль, вывод

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Создаю новый метод, прописываю туда массив:

```java
int[] taskOne = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
```

и сразу пытаюсь вывести его:

```java
System.out.println(taskOne);
```

Он же выдает мне `[I@3feba861`.
Я понимаю что вывод будет не массивом, но, вроде, должны выводиться просто цифры, нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы наблюдаете в консоли то, что возвращает метод `toString()` массива.

Чтобы вывести то, что вам нужно - напишите так:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Comment: Да, это выдает массив в правильном формате. Просто видел как на 8 java (у меня стоит 14) без этой функции в консоль выводили цифры (не в формате массива)

Comment: Мне такое не встречалось. Сколько себя помню - всегда массивы так работали)

Comment: Извиняюсь, там было условия с циклом for и выводилось taskOne[i]. ЗЫ - всем хорошего настроения)